# Point Cloud transformation error

Tags: gazebo, rviz, stere-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using **stereo_image_proc** to process data coming from a stereo system. When trying to visualize it in RVIZ I came across to the following issue: **The point cloud** *(pointcloud2 and pointcloud topics)* **is not properly transformed**. See the following images:

**In gazebo:**

https:// cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1283922/3115469/1744ac0e-e709-11e3-8e17-84c713713794.png

**In RVIZ:**

https:// cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1283922/3115472/2044a638-e709-11e3-8023-6b9ed6eeb568.png

Any ideas? Thanks..!

**P.S.: The cameras seem properly transformed.** Sorry about the links (no images/links because my karma is low). See images below:

**Left:**

https:// cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1283922/3115534/eef65dbe-e709-11e3-8ae9-793dcd54bb60.jpg

**Right:**

https:// cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1283922/3115539/fafae6fc-e709-11e3-8d06-c4366250d28e.jpg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171486/point-cloud-transformation-error/) by [costashatz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11181/costashatz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved my issue. Have a look [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/75).

---

Originally posted by [costashatz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11181/costashatz/) with karma: 11 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0